# Setting all TLS (thread local storage) variables to a new, single value in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, pthreads

I have a class Foo with the following thread-specific static member:

```
__declspec(thread) static bool s_IsAllAboutThatBass;
```

In the implementation file it is initialized like so:

```
__declspec(thread) bool Foo::s_IsAllAboutThatBass = true;
```

So far so good. Now, any thread can flip this `bool` willy nilly as they deem fit. Then the problem: at some point I want each thread to reset that `bool` to its initial `true` value.

**How can I slam all instances of the TLS to true from a central thread?**

I've thought of ways I could do this with synchronization primitives I know about, like critical sections, read/write sections, or events, but nothing fits the bill. In my real use cases **I am unable to block any of the other threads for any significant length of time.**

Any help is appreciated. Thank  you!

**Edit: Plan A**

One idea is to use a *generation token*, or *cookie* that is read by all threads and written to by the central thread. Each thread can then have a TLS for the last generation viewed by that thread when grabbing `s_isAllAboutThatBass` via some accessor. When the thread local cookie differs from the shared cookie, we increment the thread local one and update `s_isAllAboutThatBass` to `true`.

Comment: Idea, dont know if it'll work. Make it a per thread class (instead of a bool) and have its constructor register itself with a centralised system and use that system to change its value. EDIT: Looks like this wouldn't work https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w1sdazb.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mike. Really, that idea isn't bad, registering some TLS on each thread means that central system could have a map from thread ID to (in this case) a boolean, and I could do whatever I want to those values. I would essentially be re-implementing TLS though, and that sounds bad :)

Comment: Isn't the whole point of TLS that threads only access their own TLS values?

Comment: I think Plan A is a better solution for your case. Do you have some reason avoid it?

Comment: @immibis In my case, no -- I want it because it allows me to have per-thread data, and the access pattern comes along for the ride. Now, it may be that using TLS for this end is generally accepted as bad practice because of problems like this one, and that I should have a map of thread ID to data like in my other comment above. If that's true, that's a fine answer!

Comment: @yohjp Nope! I thought of it after I posted the question. I will submit it as an answer soon if nothing better comes up.

Comment: Or you could send some other message to your threads telling them to reset the variable. (If you're accessing variables from different threads, other than things like message queues, you are in for a world of headaches)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a light weighted implementation of "Plan A" with C++11 Standard [`atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) variable and [`thread_local`-specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). (If your compiler doesn't support them, please replace to vendor specific facilities.)

```
#include <atomic>

struct Foo {
  static std::atomic<unsigned> s_TokenGeneration;
  static thread_local unsigned s_LocalToken;
  static thread_local bool     s_LocalState;

  // for central thread
  void signalResetIsAllAboutThatBass() {
    ++s_TokenGeneration;
  }

  // accessor for other threads
  void setIsAllAboutThatBass(bool b) {
    unsigned currToken = s_TokenGeneration;
    s_LocalToken = currToken;
    s_LocalState = b;
  }
  bool getIsAllAboutThatBass() const {
    unsigned currToken = s_TokenGeneration;
    if (s_LocalToken < currToken) {
      // reset thread-local token & state
      s_LocalToken = currToken;
      s_LocalState = true;
    }
    return s_LocalState;
  }
};

std::atomic<unsigned> Foo::s_TokenGeneration;
thread_local unsigned Foo::s_LocalToken = 0u;
thread_local bool     Foo::s_LocalState = true;
```

Comment: +1 for atomic, which is the right answer here, and for the code structure -- they are the first step to actually hiding this complexity from the rest of the logic.

Comment: You should use `!=` instead of `<` when comparing the cookie value. Depending on how often the cookie is incremented, eventually it will overflow and wrap back to zero.  If that happens, `s_LocalToken < currToken` will not detect any further cookie changes.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is: you can't. The reason that it's called thread local storage is because only its thread can access it. Which, by definition, means that some other "central thread" can't get to it. That's what it's all about, by definition.

Now, depending on how your hardware and compiler platform implements TLS, there might be a trick around it, if your implemention of TLS works by mapping TLS variables to different virtual memory addresses. Typically, what happens is that one CPU register is thread-specific, it's set to point to different memory addresses, and all TLS variables are accessed as relative addresses.

If that is the case, you could, perhaps, derive some thread-safe mechanism by which each thread takes a pointer to its TLS variable, and puts it into a non-TLS container, that your "central thread" can get to.

And, of course, you must keep all of that in sync with your threads, and clean things up after each thread terminates.

You'll have to figure out whether this is the case on your platform with a trivial test: declare a TLS variable, then compare its pointer address in two different threads. If it's different, you might be able to work around it, in this fashion. Technically, this kind of pointer comparison is non-portable, and implementation defined, but by this time you're already far into implemention-specific behavior.

But if the addresses are the same, it means that your implementation uses virtual memory addressing to implement TLS. Only the executing thread has access to its TLS variable, period, and there is no practical means by which any "central thread" could look at other threads' TLS variables. It's enforced by your operating system kernel. The "central thread" must cooperate which each thread, and make arrangements to access the thread's TLS variables using typical means of interthread communications.

Comment: On Windows, each thread has a [Thread Information Block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block), which (amongst other things) contains a TLS array. If you use [`TlsAlloc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686801.aspx) instead of `__declspec(thread)` (which is just a wrapper for `TlsAlloc()`), you will know the index of the variable within that array. It would then be a matter of enumerating running threads, accessing each TIB and assigning a new value to the appropriate slot in its TLS array. This is lower-level programming, but doable.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie approach would work fine, and you don't need to use a TLS slot to implement it, just a local variable inside your thread procedure. To handle the case where the cookie changes value between the time that the thread is created and the time that it starts running (there is a small delay), you would have to pass the current cookie value as an input parameter for the thread creation, then your thread procedure can initialize its local variable to that value before it starts checking the live cookie for changes.

```
intptr_t g_cookie = 1;
pthread_rwlock_t g_lock;

void* thread_proc(void *arg)
{
    intptr_t cookie = (intptr_t)arg;

    while (keepRunningUntilSomeCondition)
    {
        pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&g_lock);
        if (cookie != g_cookie)
        {
            cookie = g_cookie;
            s_IsAllAboutThatBass = true;            
        }
        pthread_rwlock_unlock(&g_lock);

        //...
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void createThread()
{
    ...
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &thread_proc, (void*)g_cookie);
    ...
}

void signalThreads()
{
    pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&g_lock);
    ++g_cookie;
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&g_lock);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_rwlock_init(&g_lock, NULL);

    // use createThread() and signalThreads() as needed...

    pthread_rwlock_destroy(&g_lock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the r/w lock and inequality comparison of the cookies (instead of gt). In my case, FWIW, I was not able to have a function in my thread with a lifetime longer than a generation, so the local variable as the per-thread storage doesn't work (just a detail specific to my particular needs.)